# How do I format this Pro Micro?

Tags: microcontroller, arduino, microchip, microprocessor, arduino-uno

I am using a **Pro Micro**, which the Arduino software for sketches identifies as **Arduino Micro**.

When I plugged it into power the LED lights were too bright for my eyes to handle, so I verified and then uploaded this sketch:

```
void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:

}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  exit(0);
}
```

The problem is now the board immediately disconnects when plugged into my computer, before I can upload a new sketch onto it removing that **exit(0);** line of code above.

How can I reset this chip? :-( This was my first and favourite chip, so this is a painful experience.

Picture of the chip since I cannot remember where I bought it, but it was most likely a cheap Chinese one:
[image]

Comment: https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/57651/arduino-pro-micro-bricked  I understand you don't have a reset switch, but pulling RST low should be the same thing.

Comment: @RonBeyer Do you mean bridging the RST pin to the GND pin?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean

Comment: Compile sketch. Connect, disconnect, connect, disconnect. Then press upload sketch. Is this the correct order?